# Setting up React Testing library with NextJS, GraphQL, Apollo and i18n - Cannot destructure property

Tags: next.js, graphql, internationalization, apollo, react-testing-library

As the title suggests I'm having difficulty setting up React Testing Library on a project that uses NextJS, GraphQL, Apollo and i18n

Terminal was complaining about the router not being set up so I used `next-router-mock` to mock it as explained in their documentation and now I'm getting this error which I can't wrap my head around

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'pageTitle' of '_languageContent.default[locale]' as it is undefined.
```

[image]

```
// __tests__/index.test.jsx

import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Home from '../src/pages/index'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query"
import mockRouter from 'next-router-mock';

jest.mock('next/router', () => require('next-router-mock'));

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

describe('Home', () => {
  it('renders a heading', () => {
    mockRouter.push("/en-US");
    render(
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient} >
        <Home />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    )

    const heading = screen.getByText('stuff');

    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

My assumption is that my test is not receiving the language strings it requires - the language strings are determined by the URL - http://localhost:3000/en-US for English http://localhost:3000/fr-FR for French.

On the page component itself, a `languageContent` const is fed a variable from `useRouter` to determine which strings to use

But I have tried to set the URL with mockRouter but this did nothing

Here is the component I am trying to test

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing your import statement from `next/router` to `next/navigation`... if youre gonna use next/router then try

```
router = useRouter();
const {locale} = router;
```